# a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' while parsing XML files

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, utf-8, encode

I am trying to parse an xml that looks like this. I want to extract information regarding the katagorie i.e ID, parent ID etc:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<test timestamp="20210113">
<kategorien>
    <kategorie id="1" parent_id="0">
        Sprache
    </kategorie>
</kategorien>
</test>
```

I am trying this

```
fields = ['id', 'parent_id']

with open('output.csv', 'wb') as fp:
    writer = csv.writer(fp)
    writer.writerow(fields)
    tree = ET.parse('./file.xml')
    # from your example Locations is the root and Location is the first level
    for elem in tree.getroot():
        writer.writerow([(elem.get(name) or '').encode('utf-8') 
            for name in fields])
```

but I get this error:

```
in <module>
    writer.writerow(fields)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

even though I am already using `encode('utf-8')`  in my code. How can I get rid of this error?

Comment: Why have you particularly opened your file in `wb` mode when you have strings and not bytes?

Comment: Note: You probably want to write `for elem in tree.getroot()[0]` since `tree.getroot()` is the `test` tag and you seem to actually want to iterate over the children of `kategorien`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT 2**
If want to find regarding nested attributes or sub-classes, there are two ways:

1. You can use a nested loop:

```py
for elem in root:
    for child in elem:
        print([(child.attrib.get(name) or 'c') for name in fields])
```

Output:

> ['1', '0']

Here, it can also return for classes which have `id` and `parent_id` but not the name `kategorie`.

2. If you want to perform the task with a bit more performance and less memory:

```py
for elem in root.iter('kategorie'):
    print([(elem.attrib.get(name) or 'c') for name in fields])
```

Output:

> ['1', '0']

For this method, it will return for every class and sub-class named `kategorie`.

**EDIT 1: For the issue in comments:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<kategorien>
    <kategorie id="1" parent_id="0">
        Sprache
    </kategorie>
</kategorien>
```

For the above `xml` file, the code seems to work perfectly:

```py
fields = ['id', 'parent_id']

for elem in tree.getroot():
    print([(elem.attrib.get(name) or 'c') for name in fields])
```

Output:

> ['1', '0']

**Original Answer:**
Looks like you are looking at the wrong location for the error. The error is actually occurring at

```py
writer.writerow(fields)
```

`fields` is a list containing `str` and not `byte`, that is why it is giving you the error. I would have recommended you to change the write type from `wb` to `w`, but looking at the rest of the code, it looks like you want to write in `byte`.

```py
writer.writerow([x.encode('utf-8') for x in fields])
```

`encode()` just converts your data to `byte` form.

Comment: nah, i don't need encoding. I changed to "w" and used this ```writer.writerow([(elem.get(name) or 'c')
            for name in fields])``` but it is not able to extract the elements properly and hence, my output file only has "c" in it

Comment: You approach is little incorrect. `elem` would be just an `iterable` or the location pointer. Assuming that you have `name` set as the `attribute` of the children of `xml` file, you can do `[(elem.attrib.get(name) or 'c') for name in fields]`.

Comment: `attrib` returns a dictionary containing, `{ <attribute> : <value>}`

Comment: Can you provide a minimal reproducible example of your `xml` file.

Comment: Also, I would recommend to edit your question with the current issue you are facing.

Comment: Please check the edit in the answer

Comment: I edited my XML. Mine is nested with 1 other layer, which is why your code doesn't fit my scenario

Comment: I hope the edited version helps!

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems. First, you don't need to do the encoding yourself. Open the file without the "b" binary flag and skip .encode. The file object will do the encoding for you. The error you see comes from the `['id', 'parent_id']` list holding un-encoded strings. But if you don't open in binary in the first place, it's not a problem.

Second, you are iterating the wrong element. Add a `print(elem)` in your loop and you'll see. Instead, you can use `findall` with a pseudo-xpath to get the elements you want.

```
import csv
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

fields = ['id', 'parent_id']

with open('output.csv', 'w') as fp:
    writer = csv.writer(fp)
    writer.writerow(fields)
    tree = ET.parse('./file.xml')
    # from your example Locations is the root and Location is the first level
    for elem in tree.getroot().findall('kategorien/kategorie'):
        writer.writerow([(elem.get(name) or '') 
            for name in fields])
```